# selecting array for array_push using Ternary Operator

Tags: php

I have two arrays and I want to append to one or another based on a certain condition. The problem is that the array_push function should be called inside cases of a switch case inside a foreach loop, so using if-else means 20 extra lines of code. I thought I could do this using the Ternary Operator, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
$arr1 = ['1', '2'];
$arr2 = ['a', 'b'];
$condition = False;
array_push($condition ? $arr1 : $arr2, 'new');
```

which produces this error:
`array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) cannot be passed by reference`

I thought $arr1 and $arr2 are references, and therefore you should be able to pass them, but something is not as it should be. At least that's how it behaves in C.

Comment: After a few minutes I figured I could do it like this `$condition ? array_push($arr1, 'new') : array_push($arr2, 'new')` but I still want to know why my first solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the function signature for [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/array-push):

> `array_push(array &$array, mixed ...$values): int`

Notice the `&` in the first argument. That indicates that a reference must be passed.

Only variables can be passed by reference. A ternary *expression* is, well, an expression.

If you want to do this, you will need to first establish the reference, then pass it. And there's no easy way to shortcut that.

```
if( $condition) $ref = &$arr1; else $ref = &$arr2;
array_push($ref, 'new');
$ref = null; // clear reference
```

Comment: I did try that thinking it would work like passing pointers in C but I get syntax error(unexpected token "&")

Comment: Yup, turns out that's wrong. I don't use references often (I prefer objects) so whoopsie.